# JavaFx: ImageView disappears after moving through the scene

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I have a code written using javafx and java 11. As I showed in the below code snippet, when I move my ImageView to right of the scene, The ImageView disappears. 
At first:
[image]

and then after moving it using arrow keys with the help of scene event listener:
[image]

then:
[image]
and finally:
[image: fully disappeared]

I don't use `fxml`. Here is my demo which has the problem too.

```java
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    public String fetchResource(String path) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(path)).toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        ImageView spaceShip = new ImageView(fetchResource("spaceShip.png"));
        spaceShip.setFitHeight(100);
        spaceShip.setFitWidth(100);
        spaceShip.setX(0);
        spaceShip.setY(0);

        EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyListener = event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                spaceShip.setX(spaceShip.getX() + 20);
            }
        };


        Group game = new Group(spaceShip);

        Scene scene = new Scene(game, 1840, 1080);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyListener);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I should mention that I create a rectangle and check the scenario with that, And there was not any problem. I think there is some problem with `ImageView`.

Comment: What happens if you change `setX` / `getX` to `setTranslateX` / `getTranslateX`?

Comment: @Slaw Nothing changed!

Comment: I ran your code and could not reproduce your issue.  I downloaded this [spaceship png](https://www.pngegg.com/en/png-bcpcc) and placed it in the local resource location with the file name you use, then compiled and ran your code.  Everything worked fine for me (Mac OS X 12.2.1, JavaFX 17.0.1, OpenJDK 17.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue with your code, but I could with SceneBuilder. You may get the desired result if you wrap the `Group` in a `Pane` (at least it works in SceneBuilder).

```
Group game = new Group(spaceShip);

Pane pane = new Pane(game);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1840, 1080);

stage.setScene(scene);

stage.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I ran it on ubuntu 20.04 and java(open-jdk) 11 (maybe helpful for reproduce the issue).

Comment: Try with JavaFX 18, in case it was a bug that was fixed in a later version.  JavaFX 11 was released in 2018, Ubuntu 20 in 2020.  So JavaFX 11 may never have been coded to be compatible with Ubuntu 20.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue with Mac OS X 12.2.1 and any combination of JDK 11 or 17 and JavaFX 11, 17, or 18. But haven't tested in Ubuntu 20. IMHO there must be something else in the layout of the original code. @MohammadHossein Dolatabadi, did you check that the code in the question replicates your issue in your environment?

Comment: @Oboe Yes I did.

Comment: @MohammadHossein Dolatabadi, then I agree with jewelsea. It can be a bug of JavaFX 11 and Ubuntu 20. Did you try JavaFX 18? If the issue persists, then I would suggest issuing a bug.

Comment: @Oboe You were right. I thins it was a bug of JavaFx 11 and Ubuntu 20. I try Java 17 and problem solved! Thank you all.

Comment: @MohammadHossein Dolatabadi, I'm glad you solved your issue.